# 2FA code Tumblr not sent?

Tags: tumblr, login, multi-factor-auth

Since September, Tumblr does not send me the 2FA code any more. So I can't login any more to my account and the Tumblr support does not answer to any of my messages.

Has someone a solution to this problem?

Comment: We're probably going to need a bit more detail here.  Were you getting the 2FA codes via SMS?  Did you change carriers? etc.

Comment: This is probably a support request that should be asked of Tumblr directly.